# How do I save a dump file of a running process to a specific disk location?

Tags: windows-7, task-manager, dump

In the Windows 7 task manager, I can create a dump file of a running process by right-clicking the process entry and selecting "Create Dump File".  By default, this saves the file to the logged-on user's temp directory.

Is there a way to change where this dump file is saved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using [ProcDump](http://download.sysinternals.com/Files/procdump.zip).
Not exactly what you where asking but could solve your problem.

Comment: It turns out that the path can't be changed at all; external tools are the best I can do.